# AspectJ Pointcut Dynamic String Value based on a File content

Tags: java, aspectj, spring-aop, pointcut

I want to define a **pointcut based on a file content**. To be specific, the file would contain the package(s) to be included in the pointcut definition. I intend to read the contents of the file and define the pointcut accordingly. For instance, if the file contains a package **com.example.ClassA**. So my pointcut expression would be **within("com.example.ClassA")**. I can't just hardcode the value as the file can contain any package (or **multiple packages also**, for which I am trying to figure out another way).

Is there any way to achieve this? I know that we can't define dynamic values in pointcut expression, but this is something I want to achieve (I want to solve this without worrying about constant expression error).

I am using Spring AOP so I have to use annotations without having to create xml file(s).

Comment: _"I am using spring AOP so I have to use annotations without having to create xml file(s)."_ What is that supposed to mean? Of course you can use XML in order to configure Spring AOP and also specify pointcuts in the XML config file.

Comment: I am working on a project and that is supposed to used annotations instead of xml file configurations. I hope you understand what I am saying. That's why I said _Spring AOP_

Comment: Well, you can combine both approaches and just use XML for the aspect(s) which need textual configuration. For all the rest you continue to use annotations. You cannot eat the cake and keep it at the same time. So when your requirement is to read pointcut info from a file, why not from an XML file? The advantage is that Spring already does it for you and it is documented, no need to develop your own solution. Just use the feature and be happy. BTW, annotations are fixated on compile time, no chance to change or add anything there during runtime. This is a JVM limitation, not an AOP one.

Comment: Actually the requirement depends on user value entered in a file. We can't do that in xml, right?

Comment: Just let the user edit the XML file. If she does not know what she is doing (i.e. no-one explains it to her before she does), she will mess up the whole application anyway. BTW, I hope you do not expect this to be dynamically changeable during runtime because aspects are configured when starting up and wiring the Spring application. If you insist in making everything even more complicated, add a preprocessing step to your build or start-up script, replacing a variable in the XML file by the content of the text field. But then it is your job to maintain it. I would avoid it if I were you.